# windows phone ,how can I use WriteableBitmap and UserControl render an image?

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone

here is my code:

```
// create image1
var tileControl1 = new FlipCycleTileSmallControl("");
tileControl1.Measure(newSize(159, 159));
tileControl1.Arrange(newRect(0d, 0d, 159, 159));
var writeableBitmap1 = new System.Windows.Media.Imaging.WriteableBitmap(tileControl1, null);
image1.Source = writeableBitmap1;

// create image2 
var tileControl2 = new FlipCycleTileMediumControl("");
tileControl2.Measure(newSize(336, 336));
tileControl2.Arrange(newRect(0d, 0d, 336, 336));
var writeableBitmap2 = new System.Windows.Media.Imaging.WriteableBitmap(tileControl2, null);
image2.Source = writeableBitmap2;

// create image3
var tileControl3 = new FlipCycleTileMediumControl("");
tileControl3.Measure(newSize(691, 336));
tileControl3.Arrange(newRect(0d, 0d, 691, 336));
var writeableBitmap3 = new System.Windows.Media.Imaging.WriteableBitmap(tileControl3, null);
image3.Source = writeableBitmap3;
```

Using this code,I want to create an image from

> UserControl(FlipCycleTileSmallControl,FlipCycleTileMediumControl,FlipCycleTileMediumControl)

and save it to IsolatedStorage.

Image1 is well, but image2 and image3 are not well with black background.

What can I do?

Comment: What do you mean by not well? Please clarify.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure how you got any result from your supplied code, but it resembles some similar code that I use. In the example below, I take the user control and save an image to isolated storage. Later on I can easily reference this path.

If this isn't quite what you were hoping for, I hope it inspires a solution that sorks for you.

```
public static void SaveToIsolatedStorage(this UserControl control, string filename, Size size = new Size())
    {

        var controlWidth = (int) size.Width;
        var controlHeight = (int) size.Height;

        control.Height = controlHeight;
        control.Width = controlWidth;

        control.Arrange(new Rect(0, 0, controlWidth, controlHeight));

        // Create writeable bitmap to save as image
        var wb = new WriteableBitmap(controlWidth, controlHeight);

        // Position child objects
        control.Arrange(new Rect(0, 0, controlWidth, controlHeight));

        // Render element to bitmap
        wb.Render(control, new CompositeTransform());

        // Draw
        wb.Invalidate();

        // At this point you can do what you want with the output of writeable bitmap
        // I recommend saving to isolated storage, the access it locally.

         // Save to isolated storage
        using (var isfs = new IsolatedStorageFileStream(string.Format("/Shared/ShellContent/{0}.jpg", filename), FileMode.Create, IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication()))
        {
            wb.SaveJpeg(isfs, controlWidth, controlHeight, 0, 100);
        }

    }
```